# Shutter broke my printscreen

Tags: shutter

After i installed shutter all my screenshots looks like this:

[image]

Anyone had and fixed this problem?

EDIT: probably relevant - i'm using ubuntu 17.10

Comment: I use shutter every day... never had a problem.  What do you mean "broke my printscreen" ...  Do you mean the `PrtSc` key rather than the shutter interface?  Or all the screenshots taken with shutter are problematic?

Comment: now, even after removing shutter, screen shots make with `PrtSc` button looks like this. If i use `shift+PrtSc` all my screens look like this.

Comment: O.k. simple question when you run `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE` in terminal, what does it return?

Comment: `XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland`

Comment: O.k. just logout and start up with Ubuntu on Xorg, then shutter should work as intended.